# Wordpress Multiple meta_key (WPDB or WP_Query)

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Attempting to test whether a post has a 'main_slider', 'flickr-slider', or 'video-slider' value. 'main_slider' is a String, 'flickr-slider' and 'video-slider' are both Boolean.

This is what I have so far, which doesn't work a lick...

```
$slider = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'main_slider'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'flickr-slider'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'video-slider'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a workaround. I called each meta_key independently, merged while stripping out duplicate post, and then sorted by date. I'm sure its a heavier load on the server, but it got the job done.